# first git commit and now system beeps

Tags: git

I have my first commit which was adding a README file using

```
git commit -m 'first commit'
```

I now have the following (below) and just get system beeps when trying to navigate up or down. Not sure how to get out of it or why it has appeared.....

any help much appreciated

```
first commit

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new file:   README
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       css/
#       img/
#       index.html
~                                                                                   
~                                                                                   
~                                                                                   
~                                                                                   
-- INSERT --
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git uses vi as its default text editor. Edit your commit message, then press Esc and then type `:wq` to save and exit.

Next, if you're not familiar with vim, you should change your text editor. At the command prompt, type `git config --global core.editor editor`, replacing `editor`by whatever editor you wish to use (eg. gedit, notepad, etc.) You can find out more about basic git configs [here](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration).

Comment: You might also want to `git commit --amend` to fix the commit message if it ended up containing garbage.

Answer (score 2):

I think git opened VIM to edit the commit message. You can quit it by typing `ESC` (to go in command mode) and then typing `:wq` (To save and quit).

This probably happened because your `$EDITOR` environment value is set to `vim`. You can change it by adding `export EDITOR={your favorite editor}` to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` file.